# Apache Rewrite Rule server config troubles

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Trying to figure out how to rewrite the following in server.conf. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Have been at this for a couple hours now and can't seem to get it to work.

[www.maindomain.com/#####](http://www.maindomain.com/#####) from a url that looks like wwww.maindomain.com/?id=##### where # signs are numbers.

I have tried all types of scenario's. Here are some that I have tried

1. `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?Id=$1{QUERY_STRING}  [PT]`
2. `RewriteRule ^(.*/)$ /?Id=$1{QUERY_STRING}  [PT]`
3. `RewriteRule ^(/.*)$ /?Id=$1{QUERY_STRING}  [PT]`
4. `RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /?Id=$1{QUERY_STRING}  [PT]`

Comment: Are you trying to do an internal redirect? Make sure mod_rewrite is turned on.

Comment: Not a redirect it's a rewrite. Yes mod_rewrite is on. Thank you though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (not tested):
Change index.php to your home page file.

```
RewriteRule ^/?([\d]+) index.php?Id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: If the rule is located in a directory context (.htaccess file or <Directory> block), the leading / (right after `^`) needs to be removed or you could make it optionnal by following it by a `?` to make it valid in any context. You may also want to add the flag `QSA` as it seems the PO wants to keep any initial query string. Finally, the string to match seems to be composed of numbers so `\d` instead of `[0-9a-zA-Z_-]`? ;)

Comment: @julp, I am not really good at regex, feel free to post a seperate answer, or feel free to edit my answer :) Lemme check it

Comment: By the way, I didn't create this regex, it was a combined one taken from examples from other questions. Didnt put effort into it.

Comment: @julp I have edited it. It should probably work now. Oh, I see that the ID is composed of numbers. Also, should I escape the forward slash like `^\/?([\d]+)`? But, I am pretty sure it will work even if I escape it.

Comment: the `/` doesn't need to be escaped: it's not a metacharacter and the regexp is not delimited by a separator (like in some languages). But, you're right, surescaping won't hurt, the superfluous escape will just be ignored. It won't cause an error nor change the meaning of the pattern ;)

Comment: Hi all. First off thank you for your help. This worked perfectly. By making a few tweaks I was also able to use this on a sub page as well. My linux admin is no longer with me so I am learning as I go. I have quite a few of these that I have done but never anything that makes the main page look like a subdirectory. Thanks again! Appreciate you all.

Comment: @BradleyW.Myers You Are Welcome!